# Prevent debugging of PhoneGap app

Tags: cordova

I've created an iOS app using PhoneGap, and I learned that it's very easy to hook up your iPhone to your Mac, enable Safari debugging on the iPhone, and then use Safari on the Mac to view all the HTML and JavaScript that's part of the app.

This is great for debugging purposes, but really stinks in terms of security when I'm ready to deploy my app to the masses.  It basically means anyone can instantly see the internals of my app.

Is there any way in Phonegap to disable this type of debugging?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This only works because the `get-task-allow` entitlement is enabled for development builds. Distribution profiles do not include this entitlement, so it's not possible to attach a debugger to an app downloaded from the store. So you don't have to worry about this.

Of course that doesn't mean your code is hidden. Your javascript is still stored on the device and determined users can find another way to access it. For example users on a jailbroken device have full access to the file system and can peek inside your App's container.