# Cordova - Blocking debugging apps once into production

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I looked and all I could find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21485073/prevent-debugging-of-phonegap-app)

I know that all source in the long run can be decompiled and sniffed through for inner workings, but I just don't want it to be so damn easy.. All they need to is either use chrome debugging tools or even easier, GapDebug to look through all of my source..

Is it at all posisible to block incoming safarie/chrome debug requests?

Comment: once the app is downloaded from the app store or google play, it shouldn't be possible to debug the app

Comment: Pretty sure that it would still be debuggable, urbiwanus correctly pointed out how to disable for android.. too bad I havn't found it for WP8 or IOS

Comment: Long time ago google removed the debugable flag from the manifest (you can still use it, but it isn't there on new projects), and the debugable flag is set to true if you run the app from eclipse, and false if you export and sign it to submit it to the play store. In fact, if you have the debugable true on the manifest, play store will complain and won't let you submit the apk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android change AndroidManifest.xml to debuggable false

Combine, minify and uglify your code (i.e. http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs ). Additional you can add some useless noise code to confuse an attacker

Remove all debug statements from your code ie.console.log(...) (Performance killer too ;-) )

Since Cordova is just a web app wrapped into a native app, its damn easy to extract your source code.

Regards

Comment: is it possible to disable for IOS and WP8?